# HTTP Polling with RxJs with initial call different from the following ones

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, polling

I'm developing an `Angular 14` application and I need to poll a REST endpoint at regular intervals until I receive a certain result.

The catch, however, is that the first request I make is slightly different from the following ones (it needs an extra parameter), even though the returned type is the same. To make things clearer, here are the signatures of the two methods I'm calling (they, in turn, call the `Angular Http Client` and both return an `Observable<HttpResponse<Foo>>`):

```
export class HttpService{
    public initialCall(): Observable<HttpResponse<Foo>>{
        //...
    }
    
    public pollingCall(token: string): Observable<HttpResponse<Foo>>{
        //...
    }
}
```

To call the service, I'm using `RxJs` (I'm a total beginner with this, it should be noted) and at the moment my implementation looks like this:

```
httpService.initialCall().subscribe(
    initialResult => {
        handleIncomingFoo(initialResult.body);
        timer(3000).pipe(
            switchMap(_ => httpService.pollingCall(initialResult.body.token)),
            takeWhile(p => p.body.isRunning, true),
            repeat()
        ).subscribe(
            pollResult => {
                handleIncomingFoo(pollingResult.body);
            },
            error => {
                //Handle polling call error
            }
        );
    },
    error => {
        //Handle initial call error
    }
);
```

Basically, I first make the initial call, subscribe to it and when I get the first result I setup polling using `timer` until a certain condition is met.

However, this implementation to me seems too verbose and has a couple of drawbacks (for example: I must put the code that handles the incoming object in the separate method `handleIncomingFoo()` because I need to call it on the initial result and on the next ones as well. Also, error handling happens in two different spots).

What I want to know is simply if there is a more clever / less clunky way to write this code, maybe by chaining/combining `RxJs` operators that I don't know about. It would be ideal to only have one place in the code where the `HttpResponse<Foo>>` objects are handled, regardless of whether they come from the initial call or the following ones.

PS: notice that `pollingCall()` depends on a parameter that comes from the result of `initialCall()`, that is why I can't just put an `if(...)` inside of `switchMap` and call one method or the other based on whether we're on the first tick or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the initial call, then return an observable inside your `switchMap` that emits the initial result, followed by emissions from the polling observable.  To achive this, we can use [`concat`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat) to create a single observable from two sources and use [`of`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of) to fabricate an observable from a plain value:

```js
httpService.initialCall().pipe(
    catchError(/* handle initial error */),
    switchMap(initialResult => concat(
        of(initialResult),
        timer(3000).pipe(
            switchMap(() => httpService.pollingCall(initialResult.body.token)),
            catchError(/* handle polling error */),
            takeWhile(p => p.body.isRunning, true),
            repeat()
        )
    ))
).subscribe(
    result => handleIncomingFoo(result.body)
);
```

The benefits here are:

1. you can handle all emissions in the same place with no duplicated logic
2. you can handle errors closer to the calling code

---

If you wanted to handle the errors in the same place you could do so like this, however the stream would end when any error is received.  Handling them separately as above may give you a chance to keep the stream alive after a failure.

```js
httpService.initialCall().pipe(
    switchMap(initialResult => concat(
        of(initialResult),
        timer(3000).pipe(
            switchMap(() => httpService.pollingCall(initialResult.body.token)),
            takeWhile(p => p.body.isRunning, true),
            repeat()
        )
    ))
).subscribe(
    result => handleIncomingFoo(result.body),
    error  => handleError()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a more concise way would be to separate the two calls into single observables and then merge the output stream as following:

```
let init$ = httpService.initialCall().pipe(shareReplay());
let poll$ = timer(0, 3000).pipe(
  withLatestFrom(init$),
  switchMap(([ _, res ]) => httpService.pollingCall(res.body.token )),
  takeWhile(val => val.body.isRunning, true)
);

merge(init$, poll$).pipe(catchError(/*...*/)).subscribe(handleIncomingFoo);
```

Notes:

- You can pass a second attribute to `timer` in order to emit multiple intervals. That way you don't need `repeat`
- You should use `catchError` operator instead of passing multiple functions to `subscribe`
- If you merge the streams you only have to call `handleIncomingFoo` once

Comment: Haven't deep dived into RxJS myself too much either, but would he also need to handle unsubscribing?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I will adjust my answer.